# No internet when bridging hostapd access point with openvpn tap

Tags: networking, wireless, vpn

I've set up my RPI3 as a Wireless Access Point using hostapd. I can bridge it to the RPI3's ethernet connection without issue.

For that I simply put bridge=br0 in hostapd and then when it starts, brctl addif br0 eth0. Done. Works flawlessly. But I want to use the WLAN as an access point for a VPN.

I've setup an OpenVpn tunnel to a server in another country. 
I can use the OpenVpn client connection directly from the RPI3 no problem. I can access the local computers in the other country. I can also use the VPN servers internet.

However, when I attempt to bridge the OpenVPN tap0 interface with my access point, I can connect through the AP, yet without internet access. I can see the local computers connected to the VPN server, but that is it.

Is there some special consideration when bridging a virtual interface that I am missing?

My goal here is to be able to use the internet through the VPN as well as see broadcast traffic from the local servers at the remote location. Basically, this is for my wife, so she can watch Japanese Netflix and access a DLNA cable box at her parents house.

Comment: Investigate use of the `route` command to get a picture of what is going on (and potentially manipulate it back into shape).

Comment: What is U&L? I'm not familiar.

Comment: Sorry, there was bit of goofing around with this question; I migrated it yesterday to our big sibling [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), which when I wrote the first comment here the connection would have been obvious because of the big "migrated to our site for unix & linux" banner.  But when I came back this morning nothing had happened there, so I got it un-migrated, but the banner was still there until things were sorted at both ends, which they now are -- so I've edited those comments ;)

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get internet working through the VPN. I had thought that the clients connected to the AP were getting their IP,gateway, and DNS from the OpenVPN DHCP server. They weren't. They were only getting an IP for some reason. After manually assigning an IP, Gateway and DNS to the clients, they could connect to the internet through the VPN. Internet works great now, sadly I can't modify the VPN Server config (router integrated) to push the DHCP through .

The new problem is that it is dropping 70-90% of packets at the bridge when trying to communicate from clients to the DLNA server at the remote location. Will post a new question with details on that.

Comment: Re dropping of packets and "clients" (plural) accessing a DLNA server through it: The ethernet is limited to 100 Mbps, if by plural you mean 3+, expect it to fail for streaming media.  The pi is at best only suitable as a very small scale AP.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.